# BigNum snd stack overflow

Tags: stack, overflow, bignum

What is the BigNum and how can we work with very big numbers,like “find the sum of the even-valued terms of fibonachi sequence that the value doesn’t exceed 4 million” that we cannot put it in long long int?

Comment: What about it specifically are you asking about, and how does it relate to a Stack Overflow? If you're getting a SO as a result of a recursive function like a recursive fibino) Fibonacci function, using BigNum wont help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"BigNum" is a concept that describes the data structure that represents an arbitrary-precision number. This data structure is usually implemented as an array of digits of variable length. You can read about it here [Arbitrary-precision arithmetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

The only limit for such number representation is the amount of memory a computer can hold, so, **very** big numbers can be handled using this "BigNum". 4GB -> maximum number possible is (approximately and depends on the implementation) 2^(4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024).